AMDP Unable to use UNION ALL with local tables - sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "UNION
I have a requirement to create a table for 2 columns: first date of the month and the last day of the respective month. The last day calculation works correctly but I am not able to merge the results to a
table. When I use UNION ALL it gives an error: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "UNION
  CLASS zcl_sou_amdp_datetesting DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  INTERFACES: IF_AMDP_MARKER_HDB.
  TYPES:BEGIN OF ty_date_range,
          first_date TYPE string,
          last_day TYPE string,
        END OF TY_DATE_RANGE.
  TYPES tt_date_range_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF TY_DATE_RANGE WITH EMPTY KEY.

  CLASS-METHODS get_last_days_in_range
      IMPORTING VALUE(p_start_date) TYPE DATS
                VALUE(p_end_date) TYPE DATS
      EXPORTING VALUE(result) TYPE tt_date_range_type.


   METHOD get_last_days_in_range
    BY DATABASE PROCEDURE FOR HDB
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    OPTIONS READ-ONLY.

    DECLARE current_month DATE;
    DECLARE last_day_of_month DATE;


    result = SELECT '' AS first_date, '' AS last_day FROM dummy WHERE 1 = 0; -- Initialize empty result table

    -- Initialize current_month to the first day of the starting month
    current_month = TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(:p_start_date, 'YYYYMM') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD');

    WHILE current_month <= :p_end_date DO
        -- Calculate the last day of the current month
        last_day_of_month = LAST_DAY(current_month);

   
        -- Add the month and last Sunday to the result table
    
--The ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!!
     result = result UNION ALL
                 SELECT TO_VARCHAR(:current_month, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
                        TO_VARCHAR(:last_day_of_month, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_day
                 FROM dummy;

        -- Move to the next month
        current_month = ADD_MONTHS(current_month, 1);
    END WHILE;

  ENDMETHOD.


This is not proper SQL syntax for UNION ALL
try this:
  result = SELECT first_date, last_day 
               FROM :result
           UNION ALL  
           SELECT TO_VARCHAR(:current_month, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
                  TO_VARCHAR(:last_day_of_month, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_day
               FROM dummy;


While the accepted answer addresses the immediate issue with the UNION statement it does not address the larger problem with this procedure.
That is: this really shouldn't be a procedure in the first place.
SAP HANA (and bloody well many other DBMS) can create the list of first and last days in a given time range without looping and union.
Take this example:

SELECT 
    TO_DATS(generated_period_start) AS first_day_of_month,
    TO_DATS(LAST_DAY(generated_period_start))  AS last_day_of_month
FROM 
    series_generate_date ('INTERVAL 1 MONTH', -- increment by one month 
                          to_date ( LEFT('20240102', 6) ||'01', 'YYYYMMDD'), -- start date 
                          ADD_MONTHS(to_date(LEFT('20240402', 6) ||'01', 'YYYYMMDD') ,1 )    -- end date
                          );

Here, the built-in SERIES_GENERATE_DATE table function is used to generate all required dates. No looping, no UNION, just a SELECT.
For the input to this function we specify the step-size (INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as well as the start and end dates.
The function expects proper DATE values for those parameters, so we use the string functions LEFT and || (concatenation) to parse out the year and month components from the ABAP DATS data type and add 01 as the first day of the month.
For the end date parameter we need to add a month due to the way the SERIES_GENERATE_DATE function works. There's extensive documentation available for this - so I don't go into details on this here.
The main point is: we want the series function to generate one row for each month between and including start date and end date.
Finally, the result should return those values as DATS data types again.
This could be achieved by hand-typing in TO_VARCHAR(... , 'YYYYMMDD') but just using the built-in function TO_DATS does the trick and looks neater.
To consume this parameterised statement in ABAP, you'll probably still need to wrap it into the procedure code - however, as this is a simple SQL statement it will run much faster (relatively speaking - the original will be done within milliseconds as well) and use much fewer resources.

SERIES_GENERATE_DATE is not a AMDP but a built-in function. HANA tries to compile/optimise SQLScript before executing as much as possible. If it can be reduced to SQL, it will execute it as such. One the other hands, procedures with loops, changing data, calling other procs, etc. will have to be processed in a more expensive SQLScript context. You can check out the different execution plans via EXPLAIN or PlanViz against the CALL statement.

You wrote it was a table function, that is why I thought it was an AMDP in the end

“table function” = “function that returns a table” aka “table-valued function”.

@LarsBr. you are correct, I thought of doing that but I needed some more changes like fetching the last sunday instead of last day which required more customizations which i could not do with writing one long SERIES_GENERATE_DATE function. But glad it works. Thanks for being active in the community which has so less docu

@Sourav Das - even things like "last Sunday of a month" can be done with a single SQL statement. Think about it: SERIES_GENERATE_DATE can generate all days of your calendar - and you could just filter out the Sundays. One can then go and use e.g. aggregate functions like ROW_NUM to number the Sundays in a month. Reverse that and you got the last Sunday of the month.
Alternatively, one could just generate a calendar auxiliary table and mark the days of interest in it - much easier to look up those ;-)
